# Internals binary saving of C chars

Tags: c, utf-8

Hey i stumbled about something pretty weird while programming. I tried to transform a utf8 char into a hexadecimal byte representation like 0x89 or 0xff.

```
char test[3] = "ü";
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    printf("%x\n",test[x]);
}
```

And i get the following output :

ffffffc3

ffffffbc

0

I know that C uses one byte of data fore every one char  and therefore if i want to store an weird char like "ü" they count as 2 chars.

Transforming ASCII Chars is no problem but once i get to non ASCII Chars (from germans to chinese) instead to getting outputs like 0xc3 and 0xbc c adds 0xFFFFFF00 to them.
I know that i can just do something like &0xFF and fix that weird representation, but i can wrap my head around why that keeps happening in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C allows type `char` to behave either as a signed type or as an unsigned type, as the C implementation chooses.  You are observing the effect of it being a signed type, which is pretty common.  When the `char` value of `test[x]` is passed to `printf`, it is promoted to type `int`, in value-preserving manner.  When the value is negative, that involves [sign-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), whose effect is exactly what you describe.  To avoid that, add an explicit cast to `unsigned char`:

```
    printf("%x\n", (unsigned char) test[x]);
```

Note also that C itself does not require any particular characters outside the 7-bit ASCII range to be supported in source code, and it does not specify the execution-time encoding with which ordinary string contents are encoded.  It is not safe to assume UTF-8 will be the execution character set, nor to assume that all compilers will accept UTF-8 source code, or will default to assuming that encoding even if they do support it.

The encoding of source code is a matter you need to sort out with your implementation, but if you are using at least C11 then you can ensure execution-time UTF-8 encoding for specific string literals by using UTF-8 literals, which are prefixed with `u8`:

```
char test[3] = u8"ü";
```

Be aware also that UTF-8 code sequences can be up to four bytes long, and most of the characters in the basic multilingual plane require 3.  The safest way to declare your array, then, would be to let the compiler figure out the needed size:

```
// better
char test[] = u8"ü";
```

... and then to use `sizeof` to determine the size chosen:

```
for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(test); x++) {
    // ...
```

Comment: "*let the compiler figure out the needed size ... and then use `sizeof` to determine the size chosen*" - be aware that when using `char test[] = u8"ü";` the array will include a null-terminator, which `sizeof()` will count. Also, note that `sizeof()` counts bytes, not `char`s, but `sizeof(char)` happens to be 1, so the size and count of a `char` array will be the same value. Try this with a `wchar_t[]` array instead and they will be different values.

Comment: Yes, @Remy, the compiler will include a null terminator in the array, and count the space for it in the array size.  This is consistent with the hard-coded sizes in the OP's code, subject to their assumption that 'ü' will be encoded as two bytes.  And yes, the specifics presented would need to account for element size if generalized to another data type.  For the record, however, although `wchar_t` in particular is often larger than one byte, the specifications do not require it to be.  That's a function, in part, of which character sets are supported.